# How to specify request type to AWS lambda invocation with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a lambda function which accepts `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests. I want to invoke it using the `boto3` library for python.

According to the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke), one can invoke a lambda function with `boto3` like so:

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

But how do I specify my request type? Should my payload contain a field `method` that has `GET`/`POST`/`DELETE` in it? Or should I pass it through the `ClientContext` object/string?

Comment: Just a thought - wouldn't it be easier to directly invoke the lambda with an HTTP request?

Comment: It would, but I've been instructed specifically to use boto3 for this. That said we're using API gateway and they've published a standard event format for it, so perhaps I'll start with trying to make my payload to confer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the HTTP request in the Payload Parameter

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "routeKey": "$default",
  "rawPath": "/my/path",
  "rawQueryString": "parameter1=value1&parameter1=value2&parameter2=value",
  "cookies": [
    "cookie1",
    "cookie2"
  ],
  "headers": {
    "header1": "value1",
    "header2": "value1,value2"
  },
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "parameter1": "value1,value2",
    "parameter2": "value"
  },
  "requestContext": {
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "apiId": "api-id",
    "authentication": {
      "clientCert": {
        "clientCertPem": "CERT_CONTENT",
        "subjectDN": "www.example.com",
        "issuerDN": "Example issuer",
        "serialNumber": "a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1",
        "validity": {
          "notBefore": "May 28 12:30:02 2019 GMT",
          "notAfter": "Aug  5 09:36:04 2021 GMT"
        }
      }
    },
    "authorizer": {
      "jwt": {
        "claims": {
          "claim1": "value1",
          "claim2": "value2"
        },
        "scopes": [
          "scope1",
          "scope2"
        ]
      }
    },
    "domainName": "id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "domainPrefix": "id",
    "http": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/my/path",
      "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
      "sourceIp": "IP",
      "userAgent": "agent"
    },
    "requestId": "id",
    "routeKey": "$default",
    "stage": "$default",
    "time": "12/Mar/2020:19:03:58 +0000",
    "timeEpoch": 1583348638390
  },
  "body": "Hello from Lambda",
  "pathParameters": {
    "parameter1": "value1"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "stageVariables": {
    "stageVariable1": "value1",
    "stageVariable2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you invoke the lambda function, it doesn't have option for defining the request type.

Workaround is - you can pass that in your payload and access that in your lambda function.

Otherwise ideal approach is to invoke the function with HTTP request as already suggested.